# QScollArea doesn't autoscroll when dragging inside it

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qt4, qscrollarea

I have some widgets inside a `QScrollArea` and I'm dragging between these widgets, the problem is that the `QScrollArea` doesn't scroll when I'm dragging inside it, so if I want to drag between a widget A to the widget B and the widget B is not visible on the viewport, the `QScrollArea` doesn't automatically scroll when the mouse moves to the edge of the viewport.

Answer (score 3):

Subclass your scroll area, and add in one of the functions below.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#dragMoveEvent

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#dragLeaveEvent // Probably just need this one

When the `dragMoveEvent` reaches the edge of your widget, or when the `dragLeaveEvent` happens, detect which edge it is, or left at, and then scroll your area in that direction.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to do that, but then I discovered that the drag events from the widgets inside the QScrollArea aren't received by the QScrollArea.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html You also need to set
`setAcceptDrops(true);` for your widget.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dnd.html#dropping

Comment: Now I'm receiving the events but I'm also being able to drop on the QScrollArea which isn't what I want. Also, while I'm dragging over another widget inside the QScrollArea, I didn't receive the events on the QScrollArea.. but thanks anyway !